# How to get data from nested json array android

Tags: android, json

i am trying to get data of nested json array without success so far. maybe someone have an idea or direction how to do it right. my code is
Challenge class

```
public class ChallengeModel {

private String ChallengeID;
private String ChallengeDate;
private String ChallengeName;
private String ChallengeIcon;
private String BetID;
private ChallengeItem challengeItem[];

public String getChallengeID() { return ChallengeID; }
public void setChallengeID(String challengeID) {
    ChallengeID = challengeID;
}
public String getChallengeDate() {
    return ChallengeDate;
}
public void setChallengeDate(String challengeDate) {
    ChallengeDate = challengeDate;
}
public String getChallengeName() {
    return ChallengeName;
}
public void setChallengeName(String challengeName) {
    ChallengeName = challengeName;
}
public String getChallengeIcon() {
    return ChallengeIcon;
}
public void setChallengeIcon(String challengeIcon) {
    ChallengeIcon = challengeIcon;
}
public String getBetID() {
    return BetID;
}
public void setBetID(String betID) {
    BetID = betID;
}
public ChallengeItem[] getChallengeItem() {
    return challengeItem;
}
public void setChallengeItem(ChallengeItem[] challengeItem) { 
this.challengeItem = challengeItem; }}
```

In the above class there is an Array of nested class

```
public class ChallengeItem {

private String ChallengeItemID;
private String ChallengeID;
private String MatchID;
private String TeamAName;
private String TeamBName;
private String TeamAScore;
private String TeamBScore;
private String MatchDate;
private String MatchTime;
private String Venue;
private String VenuCity;
private String TeamAValue;
private String TeamBValue;

public String getChallengeItemID() {
    return ChallengeItemID;
}

public void setChallengeItemID(String challengeItemID) {
    ChallengeItemID = challengeItemID;
}

public String getChallengeID() {
    return ChallengeID;
}

public void setChallengeID(String challengeID) {
    ChallengeID = challengeID;
}

public String getMatchID() {
    return MatchID;
}

public void setMatchID(String matchID) {
    MatchID = matchID;
}

public String getTeamAName() {
    return TeamAName;
}

public void setTeamAName(String teamAName) {
    TeamAName = teamAName;
}

public String getTeamBName() {
    return TeamBName;
}

public void setTeamBName(String teamBName) {
    TeamBName = teamBName;
}

public String getTeamAScore() {
    return TeamAScore;
}

public void setTeamAScore(String teamAScore) {
    TeamAScore = teamAScore;
}

public String getTeamBScore() {
    return TeamBScore;
}

public void setTeamBScore(String teamBScore) {
    TeamBScore = teamBScore;
}

public String getMatchDate() {
    return MatchDate;
}

public void setMatchDate(String matchDate) {
    MatchDate = matchDate;
}

public String getMatchTime() {
    return MatchTime;
}

public void setMatchTime(String matchTime) {
    MatchTime = matchTime;
}

public String getVenue() {
    return Venue;
}

public void setVenue(String venue) {
    Venue = venue;
}

public String getVenuCity() {
    return VenuCity;
}

public void setVenuCity(String venuCity) {
    VenuCity = venuCity;
}

public String getTeamAValue() {
    return TeamAValue;
}

public void setTeamAValue(String teamAValue) {
    TeamAValue = teamAValue;
}

public String getTeamBValue() {
    return TeamBValue;
}

public void setTeamBValue(String teamBValue) {
    TeamBValue = teamBValue;
}

public String getDrawValue() {
    return DrawValue;
}

public void setDrawValue(String drawValue) {
    DrawValue = drawValue;
}

private String DrawValue;
}
```

My question is, how do i get the data from json to the nested array (The first array is working great)

```
public class ChallengeJsonConvert {

public static List<ChallengeModel> challengesRequest(String content){
    try {

        JSONArray challengesArray = new JSONArray(content);

        List<ChallengeModel> challengeModelList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < challengesArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject obj = challengesArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ChallengeModel challenge = new ChallengeModel();
            challenge.setBetID(obj.getString("BetID"));
            challenge.setChallengeDate(obj.getString("ChallengeDate"));
            challenge.setChallengeIcon(obj.getString("ChallengeIcon"));
            challenge.setChallengeID(obj.getString("ChallengeID"));
            challenge.setChallengeName(obj.getString("ChallengeName"));
            challengeModelList.add(challenge);

        }
        return challengeModelList;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

This is the results from the server

```
[
{
"ChallengeID": "1",
"ChallengeDate": "18/07/2017",
"ChallengeName": "New Challenge Arrived",
"ChallengeIcon": "icon.jpg",
"BetID": "3",
"challengeItem": [
  {
    "CallengeItemID": "5",
    "ChallengeID": "1",
    "MatchID": "845",
    "TeamAName": "FC Copenhagen (Den)",
    "TeamBName": "Zilina (Svk)",
    "TeamAScore": "0",
    "TeamBScore": "0",
    "MatchDate": "18.07.2017",
    "Venue": "Telia Parken (København)",
    "VenueCity": "København",
    "MatchTime": "17:00",
    "TeamAValue": "5.5",
    "DrawValue": "3.05",
    "TeamBValue": "1.35"
  },
  {
    "CallengeItemID": "6",
    "ChallengeID": "1",
    "MatchID": "844",
    "TeamAName": "Samtredia (Geo)",
    "TeamBName": "Qarabag (Aze)",
    "TeamAScore": "0",
    "TeamBScore": "0",
    "MatchDate": "18.07.2017",
    "Venue": "Boris Paichadze Dinamo Arena (Tbilisi)",
    "VenueCity": "Tbilisi",
    "MatchTime": "17:00",
    "TeamAValue": "5.5",
    "DrawValue": "3.05",
    "TeamBValue": "1.35"
  },
  {
    "CallengeItemID": "7",
    "ChallengeID": "1",
    "MatchID": "843",
    "TeamAName": "Alashkert (Arm)",
    "TeamBName": "BATE (Blr)",
    "TeamAScore": "0",
    "TeamBScore": "0",
    "MatchDate": "18.07.2017",
    "Venue": "",
    "VenueCity": "",
    "MatchTime": "16:00",
    "TeamAValue": "5.5",
    "DrawValue": "3.05",
    "TeamBValue": "1.35"
  },
  {
    "CallengeItemID": "8",
    "ChallengeID": "1",
    "MatchID": "842",
    "TeamAName": "Vardar (Mac)",
    "TeamBName": "Malmo FF (Swe)",
    "TeamAScore": "0",
    "TeamBScore": "0",
    "MatchDate": "18.07.2017",
    "Venue": "",
    "VenueCity": "",
    "MatchTime": "16:00",
    "TeamAValue": "5.5",
    "DrawValue": "3.05",
    "TeamBValue": "1.35"
  },
  {
    "CallengeItemID": "9",
    "ChallengeID": "1",
    "MatchID": "841",
    "TeamAName": "FC Astana (Kaz)",
    "TeamBName": "Spartaks (Lat)",
    "TeamAScore": "0",
    "TeamBScore": "0",
    "MatchDate": "18.07.2017",
    "Venue": "",
    "VenueCity": "",
    "MatchTime": "14:00",
    "TeamAValue": "5.5",
    "DrawValue": "3.05",
    "TeamBValue": "1.35"
  }
]
},
{
"ChallengeID": "2",
"ChallengeDate": "18/07/2017",
"ChallengeName": "Tuesday Funday",
"ChallengeIcon": "icon.jpg",
"BetID": "3",
"challengeItem": [
  {
    "CallengeItemID": "1",
    "ChallengeID": "2",
    "MatchID": "851",
    "TeamAName": "Lokomotiv Moscow",
    "TeamBName": "Arsenal Tula",
    "TeamAScore": "0",
    "TeamBScore": "0",
    "MatchDate": "18.07.2017",
    "Venue": "Stadion Lokomotiv (Moskva)",
    "VenueCity": "Moskva",
    "MatchTime": "16:30",
    "TeamAValue": "5.5",
    "DrawValue": "3.05",
    "TeamBValue": "1.35"
  },
  {
    "CallengeItemID": "2",
    "ChallengeID": "2",
    "MatchID": "853",
    "TeamAName": "Dinamo Moskva",
    "TeamBName": "Spartak Moskva",
    "TeamAScore": "0",
    "TeamBScore": "0",
    "MatchDate": "18.07.2017",
    "Venue": "Arena Khimki (Khimki)",
    "VenueCity": "Khimki",
    "MatchTime": "16:30",
    "TeamAValue": "5.5",
    "DrawValue": "3.05",
    "TeamBValue": "1.35"
  },
  {
    "CallengeItemID": "3",
    "ChallengeID": "2",
    "MatchID": "852",
    "TeamAName": "Spartak Moscow",
    "TeamBName": "Dynamo Moscow",
    "TeamAScore": "0",
    "TeamBScore": "0",
    "MatchDate": "18.07.2017",
    "Venue": "Otkrytiye Arena (Moskva)",
    "VenueCity": "Moskva",
    "MatchTime": "16:30",
    "TeamAValue": "5.5",
    "DrawValue": "3.05",
    "TeamBValue": "1.35"
  },
  {
    "CallengeItemID": "4",
    "ChallengeID": "2",
    "MatchID": "849",
    "TeamAName": "Vorskla Poltava",
    "TeamBName": "Shakhtar Donetsk",
    "TeamAScore": "0",
    "TeamBScore": "0",
    "MatchDate": "18.07.2017",
    "Venue": "",
    "VenueCity": "",
    "MatchTime": "16:00",
    "TeamAValue": "5.5",
    "DrawValue": "3.05",
    "TeamBValue": "1.35"
  }
]
}
]
]
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list made changes in your class copy and generate getter setter

**ChallengeModel**

```
public class ChallengeModel {
    private String ChallengeID;
    private String ChallengeDate;
    private String ChallengeName;
    private String ChallengeIcon;
    private String BetID;
    private List<ChallengeItem> challengeItem;
    //TODO
    //Generate Getter and setter
}
```

**ChallengeItem**

```
public class ChallengeItem {
    private String ChallengeItemID;
    private String ChallengeID;
    private String MatchID;
    private String TeamAName;
    private String TeamBName;
    private String TeamAScore;
    private String TeamBScore;
    private String MatchDate;
    private String MatchTime;
    private String Venue;
    private String VenuCity;
    private String TeamAValue;
    private String TeamBValue;
    //TODO
    //Generate Getter and setter
}
```

**ChallengeJsonConvert**

```
public class ChallengeJsonConvert {
    public static List<ChallengeModel> challengesRequest(String content) {
        try {
            JSONArray challengesArray = new JSONArray(content);
            List<ChallengeModel> challengeModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < challengesArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = challengesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ChallengeModel challenge = new ChallengeModel();
                challenge.setBetID(obj.getString("BetID"));
                challenge.setChallengeDate(obj.getString("ChallengeDate"));
                challenge.setChallengeIcon(obj.getString("ChallengeIcon"));
                challenge.setChallengeID(obj.getString("ChallengeID"));
                challenge.setChallengeName(obj.getString("ChallengeName"));
                JSONArray challengeItemArray = obj.getJSONArray("challengeItem");
                for (int j = 0; j < challengeItemArray.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject challengeObject = challengeItemArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    ChallengeItem challengeItem = new ChallengeItem();
                    challengeItem.setChallengeItemID(challengeObject.getString("CallengeItemID"));
                    //TODO 
                    //Get other object and set into challengeItem 
                    challenge.getChallengeItem().add(challengeItem);
                }

                challengeModelList.add(challenge);
            }
            return challengeModelList;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I copy/paste your code but the ...getChsllengeItem().add.. is red (error) + in the classes what do you mean generate getter/setter, there is a getter/setter in the class?!?!

Comment: ahhh OK OK i missed the part of the new List<>

Comment: create get and set method for all variable of model class (ChallengeItem,ChallengeModel)

Comment: I am checking that :-) i am still need to find out how to display this data in gridview. I have never done this before (until today i have deal with only 1 array gridview)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, but this is show some error. Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: OK i just replace this code: private List<ChallengeItem> challengeItem; with this code : private List<ChallengeItem> challengeItem = new ArrayList<>(); and its working

Comment: how do i print it? ie with nested for loop