# How to display inner json array in recyclerview android

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I want to show inner json array in Recyclerview.
I was getting all the data in logcat.
But my problem is how to write code in adapter class for inner array items.
My problem is like this question
[How to get data from nested json array android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277540/how-to-get-data-from-nested-json-array-android/54109393?noredirect=1#comment95052072_54109393)

I have similar json array.
I want to pass arraylist to Adapter.

This is my modal

```
public class OuterModal {
String menuId;
String menuName;
private List<InnerModal> innerItem;

public String getMenuId() {
    return menuId;
}

public void setMenuId(String menuId) {
    this.menuId = menuId;
}

public String getMenuName() {
    return menuName;
}

public void setMenuName(String menuName) {
    this.menuName = menuName;
}

public List<InnerModal> getInnerItem() {
    return innerItem;
}

public void setInnerItem(List<InnerModal> innerItem) {
    this.innerItem = innerItem;
}
```

}

This is my another modal

```
public class InnerModal {
String vendor_item_id;
String vendor_id;
String vendor_item_name;
String vendor_item_image;
String vendor_item_price;
String vendor_item_category;
String vendor_item_description;
String vendor_item_status;

public String getVendor_item_id() {
    return vendor_item_id;
}

public void setVendor_item_id(String vendor_item_id) {
    this.vendor_item_id = vendor_item_id;
}

public String getVendor_id() {
    return vendor_id;
}

public void setVendor_id(String vendor_id) {
    this.vendor_id = vendor_id;
}

public String getVendor_item_name() {
    return vendor_item_name;
}

public void setVendor_item_name(String vendor_item_name) {
    this.vendor_item_name = vendor_item_name;
}

public String getVendor_item_image() {
    return vendor_item_image;
}

public void setVendor_item_image(String vendor_item_image) {
    this.vendor_item_image = vendor_item_image;
}

public String getVendor_item_price() {
    return vendor_item_price;
}

public void setVendor_item_price(String vendor_item_price) {
    this.vendor_item_price = vendor_item_price;
}

public String getVendor_item_category() {
    return vendor_item_category;
}

public void setVendor_item_category(String vendor_item_category) {
    this.vendor_item_category = vendor_item_category;
}

public String getVendor_item_description() {
    return vendor_item_description;
}

public void setVendor_item_description(String vendor_item_description) {
    this.vendor_item_description = vendor_item_description;
}

public String getVendor_item_status() {
    return vendor_item_status;
}

public void setVendor_item_status(String vendor_item_status) {
    this.vendor_item_status = vendor_item_status;
}
```

}

This is JSON Responce

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        mainUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("menu");
                            List<OuterModal> outerModalList=new ArrayList<>();
                            OuterModal outerModal=new OuterModal();
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String menu_id = json.getString("menu_id");
                                String menu_name = json.getString("menu_name");
                                outerModal.setMenuId(menu_id);
                                outerModal.setMenuName(menu_name);
                                JSONArray productsListArray = json.getJSONArray("Products List");
                                for (int j = 0; j < productsListArray.length(); j++) {

                                   // Log.d("myDraaa", "list responce:" + productsListArray);

                                    JSONObject productsListjson = productsListArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                    InnerModal innerModal=new InnerModal();
                                    List<InnerModal> innerModalList=new ArrayList<>();
                                    String vendor_item_id = productsListjson.getString("vendor_item_id");
                                    String vendor_id = productsListjson.getString("vendor_id");
                                    String vendor_item_name = productsListjson.getString("vendor_item_name");
                                    String vendor_item_image = productsListjson.getString("vendor_item_image");
                                    String vendor_item_status = productsListjson.getString("vendor_item_status");
                                    String quantity = productsListjson.getString("quantity");
                                    innerModal.setVendor_id(vendor_id);
                                    innerModal.setVendor_item_id(vendor_item_id);
                                    innerModal.setVendor_item_category("");
                                    innerModal.setVendor_item_description("");
                                    innerModal.setVendor_item_image(vendor_item_image);
                                    innerModal.setVendor_item_name(vendor_item_name);
                                    innerModal.setVendor_item_status(vendor_item_status);
                                    innerModal.setVendor_item_price(quantity);

                                    outerModal.getInnerItem().add(innerModal);
                                }
                                outerModalList.add(outerModal);
                            }


public class SecondAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SecondAdapter.SecondVH> {
    List<OuterModal> arrayList;
    Context context;
    public SecondAdapter(List<OuterModal> arrayList, Context context) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SecondVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_style, null, false);
        return new SecondVH(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SecondVH holder, final int position) {

        OuterModal outerModal=arrayList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(outerModal.getMenuName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class SecondVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView items;
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

        TextView itemName, itemPrice, itemDescription;


        public SecondVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bestSellers);
            items = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myCustItemName);
            constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.csL);
            itemPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
            itemDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemDesc);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Please help me.

Comment: Please add your code what you have tried and errors which you get. you can remove url for security reasons. and add a json data response

Comment: simply create Model class for that inner array and create its list and pass it to Adapter. kindly add json response.

Comment: I have same type url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277540/how-to-get-data-from-nested-json-array-android/54109393?noredirect=1#comment95052072_54109393

Comment: Please see my code above

Comment: I want to show data when i click on menu item it will show the inner arraylist

Comment: Click on menu and show inner arraylist, just wondering how will your UI looks like ?

Comment: BTW, just create a sub model class, and put it into main model class, just like "order & order detail" concept.

Comment: My UI like Food panda menu item @RRTW.

Comment: I was already do that one but I don't know how to write code in my adpater